# WIndows 11 updating 21h2 to 22h2 FatalError in setupact.log, in migcore.dll, and 22h2 update always rolls back

Tags: windows-11, windows-update, windows-11-v22h2

My Windows 11 Pro workstation versopm 21H2 build 22000.2416 system has been on Win11 21h2 builds thus far and keeps trying to install updates to 22h2 which fails with an error, either when run through windows update, or run externally.  All the usual Windows Update resets and checks have been tried, in brief all services have been repaired and checked, and all common general windows system integrity check commands have completed without errors.  This has now happened in excess of 30 times.  This error occurs both with and without any third party Anti-virus  installed.

In general the repeating error is:

ACCESS_VIOLATION) occurred at 0x00007FFBABA1FAA9 in C:$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\migcore.dll (+00000000002AFAA9).

This error is reported in the setupact.log located at C:$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\setupact.log

SetupDiag.exe zipped logs attached.

Net result is system won't upgrade to 22h2.  I have spoken to my work colleagues and several of them have the same error.

full Setup Logs could be attached if thats within the rules at SuperUser. If I can figure out other relevant details I will update the question to contain them.

Windows 11 Repair Install was done, and had no effect.
All the usual elevated command prompt commands to check system files including sfc.exe /scannow were done.

Highlights of the setupact.log are provided:

```
2023-09-20 19:46:56, Info       [0x080489] MIG    Setting system object filter context (System)
2023-09-20 19:46:56, Info       [0x0803e6] MIG    Removing mapping for HKCU\Software\Classes
2023-09-20 19:46:56, Info       [0x0803e7] MIG    Successfully unmapped HKCU\Software\Classes
2023-09-20 19:46:56, Info       [0x0803e6] MIG    Removing mapping for HKCU
2023-09-20 19:46:56, Info       [0x0803e7] MIG    Successfully unmapped HKCU
2023-09-20 19:46:56, Info       [0x080489] MIG    Setting system object filter context (System)
2023-09-20 19:46:56, Info       [0x0803e6] MIG    Removing mapping for HKCU\Software\Classes
2023-09-20 19:46:56, Info       [0x0803e7] MIG    Successfully unmapped HKCU\Software\Classes
2023-09-20 19:46:56, Info       [0x0803e6] MIG    Removing mapping for HKCU
2023-09-20 19:46:56, Info       [0x0803e7] MIG    Successfully unmapped HKCU
2023-09-20 19:46:56, Info       [0x080411] MIG    Setting SMI registry mappings for system context
2023-09-20 19:46:56, Info                  MIG    MigHost: CMigPluginSurrogate::COMGenericThreadingHostThreadProc: Exiting ThreadID=[0x2698].
2023-09-20 19:46:56, Info                  MIG    MigHost: CMigPluginSurrogate::COMGenericThreadingHostThreadProc: Exiting ThreadID=[0x290c].
2023-09-20 19:46:56, Info                  MIG    MigHost: CMigPluginSurrogate::COMGenericThreadingHostThreadProc: Exiting ThreadID=[0x120c].
2023-09-20 19:47:16, Info                  CBS    TI: Rejected an auto-stop attempt, because WinLogon CreateSession notification has not been called (will not report again) 
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Error      [0x0808b4] MIG    MigHost: CMigPluginSurrogate::FreeSurrogate: hThread=0x57c, ThreadId=0x24a4, timeout.[gle=0x00000057]
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  MIG    COutOfProcPluginFactory::FreeSurrogateHost: Shutdown in progress.
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  MIG    MigHost: Exiting process.
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Error      [0x08038d] MIG            Failure while calling IPostApply->ApplySuccess for Plugin={ServerPath="%systemroot%\system32\migration\shmig.dll", CLSID={050ed09e-a530-41e6-8ac9-a9a96e74a2c1}, ThreadingModel=Apartment, ExceptionHandling=Default}. Error: 0x800706BE
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  SP             Will add an extra error
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Error                 SP             Error READ, 0x000006BE while gathering/applying object: apply-success, Action,CMXEPlugin,C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Work\MachineIndependent\Working\agentmgr\CCSIAgent,%systemroot%\system32\migration\shmig.dll,{050ed09e-a530-41e6-8ac9-a9a96e74a2c1},Apartment,Default. Will return 2[gle=0x000000cb]
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  MIG            Error 0x000006BE while executing action Action,CMXEPlugin,C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Work\MachineIndependent\Working\agentmgr\CCSIAgent,%systemroot%\system32\migration\shmig.dll,{050ed09e-a530-41e6-8ac9-a9a96e74a2c1},Apartment,Default. Shell application requested ignore
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  SP             PLUGINPROC: Adding to an existent plugin: Action,CMXEPlugin,C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Work\MachineIndependent\Working\agentmgr\CCSIAgent,%systemroot%\system32\migration\shmig.dll,{050ed09e-a530-41e6-8ac9-a9a96e74a2c1},Apartment,Default
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  MIG            Processing APPLY-SUCCESS for migration unit: <WarrenAlienware\warre>\additional_options\additional_options\windows_core_settings\Microsoft-Windows-RasMprDdm (CCSIAgent)
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  MIG            Processing APPLY-SUCCESS for migration unit: <WarrenAlienware\warre>\additional_options\additional_options\windows_core_settings\Microsoft-Windows-feclient (CCSIAgent)
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  MIG            Processing APPLY-SUCCESS for migration unit: <WarrenAlienware\warre>\Microsoft-Windows-AppManagement-Migration (CCSIAgent)
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  SP             PLUGINPROC: Adding to an existent plugin: Action,CMXEPlugin,C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\ReplacementManifests,Microsoft-Windows-AppManagement-Migration\AppManMigrationPlugin.dll,{2AF7D9A3-FA1C-410A-B6D3-C6AD32232531},Apartment,Default
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  MIG            Processing APPLY-SUCCESS for migration unit: <WarrenAlienware\warre>\appearance_and_display\appearance_and_display\taskbar_and_start_menu\Microsoft-Windows-stobject (CCSIAgent)
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  MIG            Processing APPLY-SUCCESS for migration unit: <WarrenAlienware\warre>\network_and_internet\network_and_internet\networking_connections\Microsoft-Windows-MPR (CCSIAgent)
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  MIG            Processing APPLY-SUCCESS for migration unit: <WarrenAlienware\warre>\performance_and_maintenance\performance_and_maintenance\diagnostics\Microsoft-Windows-RemoteAssistance-Exe (CCSIAgent)
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  MIG            Processing APPLY-SUCCESS for migration unit: <WarrenAlienware\warre>\Microsoft-Windows-WMPNSS-Service (CCSIAgent)
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  MIG            Processing APPLY-SUCCESS for migration unit: <WarrenAlienware\warre>\Microsoft-Windows-IE-PDM-Configuration (CCSIAgent)
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  MIG            Processing APPLY-SUCCESS for migration unit: <WarrenAlienware\warre>\Microsoft-Windows-ScriptedDiagnosticsClient-Scheduled (CCSIAgent)
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  MIG            Processing APPLY-SUCCESS for migration unit: <WarrenAlienware\warre>\Microsoft-Windows-OfflineFiles-Core (CCSIAgent)
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  MIG    COutOfProcPluginFactory::LaunchSurrogateHost::CommandLine: "C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\mighost.exe" {9E2DD24E-AEE3-426E-9AD4-3288052C21E0} /InitDoneEvent:MigHost.{9E2DD24E-AEE3-426E-9AD4-3288052C21E0}.Event /ParentPID:2604 /LogDir:"C:\Windows\Panther"
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  MIG    MigHost started with command line: {9E2DD24E-AEE3-426E-9AD4-3288052C21E0} /InitDoneEvent:MigHost.{9E2DD24E-AEE3-426E-9AD4-3288052C21E0}.Event /ParentPID:2604 /LogDir:"C:\Windows\Panther"
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  MIG    MigHost: CMigPluginSurrogate::Init: Successfully initialized surrogate.
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  MIG    MigHost: Initialized successfully with CLSID[{9E2DD24E-AEE3-426E-9AD4-3288052C21E0}] and LogDir=[C:\Windows\Panther]
2023-09-20 19:47:26, FatalError [0x090001] PANTHR         Exception (code 0xC0000005: ACCESS_VIOLATION) occurred at 0x00007FFBABA1FAA9 in C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\migcore.dll (+00000000002AFAA9).  Minidump attached (97390 bytes) to diagerr.xml and C:\Windows\Panther\mndCF6A.diagerr.mdmp.
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  SP     SETUPPLATFORMCOMM: Progress message received: Phase: OOBE Boot, Operation: Migrate data, Percentage: 57%
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Warning    [0x08094f] MIG    MigHost: CMigPluginSurrogate::WaitForHostTermination: Parent process unexpectedly exited. Terminating host.
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  MIG    MigHost: Exiting process.
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  SP     WINDEPLOY error code is 0xC0000005. Will not attempt uninstall
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  CBS    Trusted Installer signaled for shutdown, going to exit.
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  CBS    Trusted Installer is shutting down because: SHUTDOWN_REASON_NOTIFICATION:PRESHUTDOWN
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  CBS    TiWorker signaled for shutdown, going to exit.
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  CBS    Deleting the contents of directory: \\?\C:\WINDOWS\CbsTemp
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  CBS    Deletion of: \\?\C:\WINDOWS\CbsTemp successful
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  CBS    CbsCoreFinalize: ExecutionEngineFinalize
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  CBS    Execution Engine Finalize
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  CBS    Execution Engine Finalize
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  CBS    Execution Engine Finalize
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  CBS    Execution Engine Finalize
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  CBS    Lock: Lock removed: TiWorkerClassFactory, level: 30, total lock:3
2023-09-20 19:47:26, Info                  CBS    Lock: Lock removed: CCbsWorker, level: 5, total lock:2
```

17 megs zipped logs:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1emucy9StkGuB7i-g9txrW0JVC2YvUC5k/view?usp=sharing

SetupDiagResults.log is terse enough to show here.

```
Matching Profile found: DebugSetupCrash - CEEBA202-6F04-4BC3-84B8-7B99AED924B1
SetupDiag version: 1.7.0.0
System Information:
    Machine Name = WARRENALIENWARE
    Manufacturer = Alienware
    Model = Alienware Aurora R12
    HostOSArchitecture = x64
    FirmwareType = UEFI
    BiosReleaseDate = 20230314000000.000000+000
    BiosVendor = 1.1.20
    BiosVersion = 1.1.20
    HostOSVersion = 10.0.22000
    HostOSBuildString = 22000.1.amd64fre.co_release.210604-1628
    TargetOSBuildString = 10.0.22621.2283 (ni_release_svc_prod1.230831-1007)
    HostOSLanguageId = 1033
    HostOSEdition = Professional
    RegisteredAV = Windows Defender
    FilterDrivers = FileInfo
    UpgradeStartTime = 9/20/2023 3:20:48 PM
    UpgradeEndTime = 9/20/2023 7:47:26 PM
    UpgradeElapsedTime = 04:26:38
    RollbackStartTime = 9/20/2023 7:47:59 PM
    RollbackEndTime = 9/20/2023 7:50:43 PM
    RollbackElapsedTime = 00:02:44
    CV = OmFzOMisxE+BnnzN
    ReportId = 2D375561-4821-488D-BA0A-8269AEBF51BC

DebugSetupCrash
Found qualifying memory dump during setup, but the debugger binaries were not found. Either examine the memory dump here: C:\Windows\Panther\NewOS\Panther\mndB9BF.diagerr.mdmp or install the debugger tools from here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/ to determine the failure.

Last Setup Phase:
Phase Name: Pre OOBE Boot
    Phase Started: 9/20/2023 7:44:36 PM
    Phase Ended: 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
    Phase Time Delta: 00:00:00
    Completed Successfully? False


Last Setup Operation:
Operation Name: Machine-independent apply
    Operation Started: 9/20/2023 7:44:39 PM
    Operation Ended: 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
    Operation Time Delta: 0:00:00:00.0000000
    Completed Successfully? False
```

Update: Above shows me that I need to install windbg and associated moving parts so setupdiag can do analysis and print a result.

Comment: Try running a Windows 11 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation link. Use the option to Keep Everything.  See if that fixes the update issue

Comment: Run [Setup Diagnostic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/setupdiag) and provide the results. We don't need the entire log, only the relevant information, from the logs.  Hundreds of Megabytes worth of logs, that contain failures from multiple days, won't be looked at by most users. What May 2023 question are you referring to?

Comment: Define relevant.  I have provided the fatal error that causes the rollback.  Not sure how much of the zipped logs that SetupDiag produces is relevant.
The logs are 16 megs. Providing a google drive link here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1emucy9StkGuB7i-g9txrW0JVC2YvUC5k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If it is possible to extract a calls tack from this minidump perhaps it's relevant...

C:\Windows\Panther\mndCF6A.diagerr.mdmp.

I am not sure how to turn this mdmp minidump into a callstack.

Windows itself has a pitiful UI for reporting errors installing updates, and finding the relevant data requires pretty advanced knowledge of the rather crappy files like minidumps and .etl files and the crap windows tooling around them.    If I was the lead at MIcrosoft responsible for WIndows installer and updater, I'd be ashamed of how fragile MigHost and MigCore are.

Comment: The prior question turns out to have been unrelated, and was closed due to missing basic information.

Comment: @WarrenP - You have no closed questions.  Memory dumps won't be helpful. SetupDiag should be enough to diagnose what is preventing the upgrade. Are you perhaps on a Windows Insider Preview build? So what is the value of `RedReason` contained within `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\TargetVersionUpgradeExperienceIndicators\NI22H2`?

Comment: NOt on a preview build. ON a recent 21h2 build. 221H2 2000.2416

RedReason = None

UpgEx = Green

Comment: I lied before, analysis of WinDBG on the memory dump created during the failed upgrade attempt (mndB9BF.diagerr.mdmp) will be required. We don’t need the memory dump, we need the analysis, output from WinDBG. SetupDiag probably could do that for you but since the debugging binaries were not installed.

Comment: So I am on 21h2 so I need to install the 21h2 windows 11 sdk to get debug binaries and windbg?